# No data from socket activation with systemd

Tags: node.js, systemd

I've got two little systemd socket and service files:

Socket:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=80
# also tried with Accept=no

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Webserver

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/node-script.env
ExecStart=/path/to/node /path/to/server.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=node-script
Type=simple
User=test-user
Group=test-user

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Env:

```
PORT=80
```

I've got a tiny Node.js script:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('connection', function(conn) {
  // socket connection
  console.log('new connection', conn.address());
  conn.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('more data', data.length);
  });
}).on('request', function(req, res) {
  // a request!
  console.log('new request', req.headers);
}).listen({fd: 3}, function() {
  console.log('listening on provided descriptor', server.address());
});
```

If I start it up:

```
$ systemctl start node-script.socket
$ curl localhost
```

Curl just sits there. Same thing if I try to directly netcat data into the socket. Checking the logs, I note that the server got a connection, but never got any data or a request.

```
listening on provided descriptor { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 80 }
new connection { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 80 }
```

Where's the data going?

Comment: If you start your app from the command line, `/path/to/node /path/to/server.js` does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've since worked around my issue, though I do not recall how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else encounters this problem: In the systemd `[Service]` section, you need to add this line:

```
NonBlocking=True
```

Though this should only be necessary for old releases; node.js was fixed to set the non-blocking flag itself somewhere in the 0.12 series.